# backspace in vim deletes a whole word instead of one character

Tags: vim

I think I need a setting to prevent vim (6.0) to delete an entire word instead of a character when I press a backspace. please suggest!

Comment: Why aren't you using Vim 7.0?

Comment: I just realised that you might be stating that backspace *does* delete a whole word for you, and you only want it to delete a single character. Is that correct? If so, then my answer is the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, if you want to *prevent* it deleting a word when you press , then discard a non-default configuration you have imposed for vim to do so.

Or try

```
:iunmap <BS>
```

and report if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:imap`:

```
:imap <C-?> <C-W>
```

Depending on your terminal settings, you may need to use `<C-H>` instead of `<C-?>`. Note that the above characters are typed literally (less-than, C, dash, ?, greater-than, etc).